# Are there issues with using .any() within mvc views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, .net-core

We are experiencing an issue where the use of the .Any() linq method causes an error in an MVC partial view.  The error being that the use of the method causes a null reference error - the same linq code within the controller does not cause this issue.  .

```
<div class="row">
@{
    //This line causes the page to throw an error:
    var isSelected = Model.ListOfReferenceType.Any(c => c.ReferenceType.Id == listTypeId);

    @if (isSelected)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="SomeCheckBox" id="SomeCheckBox" checked="checked" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="SomeCheckBox" id="SomeCheckBox" />
    }

}
</div>
```

Is this a known issue where some of the linq functions cause issues with the rendering engine?

Note, we are using .net core and nancy - don't know whether this provides any insights.

Comment: Any time you have an error, it's helpful to share exactly what that error is as part of your question.

Comment: Are you sure your ListOfReferenceType contains what you think it does, and that every object in that list has a valid ReferenceType in it that you can call .Id on?  Because that would be way higher on my list than "maybe I can't use .Any() in an MVC view". ;)

Comment: Is `Model` NULL ? Is `Model.ListOfReferenceType` NULL ?

Comment: Thanks Marc and Shyju, yes, the issue was not including the underlying object.  So, the any wasn't failing.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid this, add a construtor do your Model if you don't have one and inside the construtor initiate the property ListOfReferenceType. This will avoid the property to be null.

```
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        this.data = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `.Any`returns `null` than the source or predicate is `null`.

[Enumerable.Any Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)